# Prove the stopped process $A^{S(k)}$ is previsible

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

I have a different attempt in mind, but I'm guessing it's wrong because if it were right, the book would've used it.

It seems that we must show that

$$A_{S_k \wedge n} \ \in \ m \mathscr F_{n-1}$$

---

**Case 1**: $$n \le S_k$$

$$A_{S_k \wedge n} = A_{n} \ \in \ m \mathscr F_{n-1}$$

---

**Case 2**: $$n > S_k \iff n-1 \ge S_k$$

$$A_{S_k \wedge n} = A_{S_k} \ \in \ m \mathscr F_{S_k}$$

Since $\mathscr F_{S_k} \subseteq \mathscr F_{n-1}$,

$$A_{S_k} \ \in \ m \mathscr F_{n-1}$$

QED

Did I go wrong somewhere?
Are we forbidden from using a stopping time for a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: All your reasonings based on "Case 1: $n \le S_k$ / Case 2: $n > S_k$" dichotomies, or their variants, are utterly wrong since $S_k$ is a random variable, not a number. I lost the count of your recent questions where you use this argument -- anyway you can erase them all.

Comment: @Did what do you mean? For a certain omega, $S_k(\omega)$ is a number right?